# How to remove "restore defaults" and "apply" button in custom RCP Preference Page

Tags: java, eclipse, swt, eclipse-rcp, rcp

When creating a preference page in RCP, e.g. something like:

```
public class MyPreferencePage extends org.eclipse.jface.preference.PreferencePage  implements IWorkbenchPreferencePage
```

how can I remove the "Restore default values" and "Apply" buttons which get added by default.
Using

```
this.getDefaultsButton().setVisible(false);
this.getApplyButton().setVisible(false);
```

results in an error.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Call `PreferencePage.noDefaultAndApplyButton()` before your control is created.

Comment: Wow, how could I miss that? By the way, noDefaultAndApplyButton() is not a static method, so it needs to be called on the object not on the class.

Comment: Yes, I know it's not static, it's just the way I write the method, it was not a suggested line of code :)

Answer (score 0):

use this [noDefaultAndApplyButton()](http://help.eclipse.org/indigo/topic/org.eclipse.platform.doc.isv/reference/api/org/eclipse/jface/preference/PreferencePage.html#noDefaultAndApplyButton%28%29) before your code begins